# Exit pthread that is executing

Tags: c, pthreads

How do I self-terminate pthread execution?

I have this code

```
while(1)
{
  if(...)
  {
    terminate
  }
  work();
}
```

I have to use `pthread_exit();` but what do I give as parameter?

Comment: I believe you can simply `return 0` from the thread as well, and that will lead to an implicit call to `pthread_exit`.

Comment: are you sure return will call pthread_exit? i searched for thsi but didnt find any fact saying this

Comment: No I'm not, been ages since I touched posix threads, but that's what [RTFM](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_exit) says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manuals

> The `pthread_exit()` function terminates the calling thread and returns
>          a value via `retval` that (if the thread is joinable)  is  available  to
>          another thread in the same process that calls `pthread_join(3)`.

This is any value you want to provide to the joining thread. If you do not need a return value, you can pass `NULL`.

Comment: that does not make any sense at all, and I am not even sure if `pthread_t` is a pointer; in any case `pthread_join` requires a thread as an argument, so the other thread knows the `pthread_t` already.